# Flutter convert math equation into image of math

Tags: flutter, dart, math

Is there a way to get a math input in flutter from the user
for example:

```
var input = sqrt((x+5)/5)
```

and to present it as a widget like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can convert your equation to a TeX formula, you can render it using the [catex](https://pub.dev/packages/catex) package.